# Make fields optional in WooCommerce My account edit addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, account

How to make all fields optional in WooCommerce My account edit addresses only?

How to disable the required notice:

[image: required notice]

And the required html:

[image: required html]

How to remove required? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make all My account > addresses fields optional use the following:

```php
// Make all My account addresses fields optional
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'filter_my_account_addresses_fields', 999 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_my_account_addresses_fields', 999 );
function filter_my_account_addresses_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on My account edit addresses
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {
        // Loop through existing fields
        foreach( $fields as $field_key => $field_data ) {
            // if they are required
            if( $fields[$field_key]['required'] ) {
                // Make them optional
                $fields[$field_key]['required'] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}

// Optionaly remove ("optional)" text from My account addresses fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_account_addresses_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_account_addresses_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on My account edit addresses
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I have a question
There are individual and corporate options on the payment page.
checkout page everything works fine.
but. My account has options for address correction. but whether he chose it does not work. what can I do? I would be very happy if you review our site. I will have no other questions. https://kukcicek.com

Comment: @SelmanGüneri Sorry I don't catch… What do you mean by "My account has options for address correction. but whether he chose it does not work…"? What are that "options"? What is the problem, can you be more explicit?

Answer (score -1):

[works for option on checkout page "kurumsal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGEZR.png)

[works for option on checkout page "bireysel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imOGC.png)

[my account > addresses - does not select and hide option and does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTePG.png)

[my account > addresses - does not select and hide option and does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtQtk.png)

you can understand in the picture

Comment: As this is not an answer, you should delete it and add it as an edit at the end of your question… I think that you are not clear… Do you want to remove some fields? We don't understand what your problem is, so try explain it with words… Once done notify me with a comment under my answer.